# How would I redirect requests for one page to another is IIS?

Tags: iis, redirect

How would I redirect requests to a URL like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/foo.aspx
```

to another URL like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bar.aspx
```

in IIS.

Can this be done in IIS 6.0 or 7.0?

Comment: ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a few ways you can do it

1) Response.Redirect
2) Server.Transfer (though it will still appear as "foo.aspx"
3) Use URL Rewriting to redirect the user before it gets to ASP.NET

All can be done on both IIS6 and 7, although IIS6 would require an ISAPI URL Rewriting module, IIS7 has a module built in.